# -Objc Linker Flag between two framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I have **two** frameworks, one of them need to use **-ObjC** and other doesn't.
If I add **-ObjC**, first framework work but second doesn't.
Also have same thing if I removed.
Is there way to link which framework with ObjC or any others way to solve?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Not enough information.  What are the frameworks?  What are the symbols that need `-ObjC` in order to avoid link errors?

Comment: Can you post your exact error when run the app?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: <br/> 
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", 
referenced from: <br/> 
      objc-class-ref in AWSCore(AWSMobileAnalyticsIOSSystem.o)  <br/>  

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 <br/> 

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Two framework are  <br/> QuickBlox & AWSCore

Answer (score 0):

You should use "-force_load " instead of "-ObjC". The "-ObjC" flag applies to all libraries, but the "-force_load " only applies to the library you specify.

Comment: FYI, -force_load $(SOURCE_ROOT)/<PATH_TO_DIR>/frameworkA.framework/Versions/Current/frameworkA

Comment: Any idea how to use -force_load with Cloudinary?